# Bootstrap 3, full height container without scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a bootstrap layout with header, sticky footer, and 2 fluid containers. one of which is of fixed height, and the other must take all remaining height.

currently i tried to accomplish this by setting height to 100% for second container, but unfortunately it adds scroll to window. How can I make container2 to fill available height, so it does not add the scroll to window.

```
<div id="app" class="height100">
  <div class="height100">
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
  NAVBAR
</div>
<div class="container-fluid container1">
  CONTAINER 1
</div>
<div class="container-fluid container2">
  CONTAINER 2
</div>
<div class="footer">
  FOOTER
</div>
```

```
html,
body,
.height100 {
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: red;
}

.container1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 105px;
}

.container2 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
}

.footer {
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: #ddd 1px solid;
  padding-top: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shkipper/no83psx3/2/)

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set overflow to hidden .
**CSS**

```
.height100
  {
  height: 100%;
 overflow:hidden;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/no83psx3/4/

Comment: thx for reply. but this does not change the height of container2, and what i needed is to fill available height, without hiding the scroll, so i can later use container2 height in js.

Comment: Try to give ,div with class height100 a height of 100 vh

Comment: got it working with min-height: calc(100vh - 155px);